# Read file content using TextReader requires full path of file - Beginner

Tags: c#

I have taken a `IFormFile` as an input and I need to read its content.

And, I am going to read the file content using the following code. However, `File.OpenText` requires a file path as input.

```
TextReader fileReader = File.OpenText(pathToFile)
```

Since I am not going to save the file in a physical location I have no file path with me at hand to pass to `File.OpenText` as an input.

How can I solve this ?

```
public async Task<string> PdfFileSave(IFormFile file, string nameOfThePerson)
{

     TextReader fileReader = File.OpenText(pathToFile);
}
```

Comment: If it's coming from an http request then it's in request not on the file system. Even if you were going to save it to disk you wouldn't read it from disk.

Comment: Ok but, is there a way I could have a `TextReader ` object. Can you help out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
    byte[] fileBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileBytes);
}
```

Comment: I need a TextReader  object finally. How Can I get it from your code.

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand that. So, try: `TextReader a = new StreamReader( file.OpenReadStream() );`. Be sure use that inner using statment.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  File.OpenReadStream():

```
public async Task<string> PdfFileSave(IFormFile file, string nameOfThePerson)
{

     TextReader fileReader = new StreamReader( file.OpenReadStream() );
}
```